# Returning to a specific section of the View from the controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to do a one-page website on asp.net core and I want to try to return from the controller to a specific part of the web page.

I have each page into sections of the cshtml file and have given each of them Ids in order to navigate between them.

Is there a way from the controller to go to a specific section of my page.

```
<section id="contact">
    <form asp-action="PostEmail" asp-controller="Home">
        <div class="text-center">
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
            &nbsp;

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
            </div>
            &nbsp;

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message)
            </div>
            &nbsp;
            <div>
                <button type="submit">Submit Message</button>
            </div>
            &nbsp;
            <div class="font-weight-bold text-danger">
                @ViewBag.message
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

--- controller I want to return from to the section id contact

```
 public IActionResult PostEmail(Contact contact)
        {
return View();
        }
```

There are other sections on this one page so imagine other sections on the page.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in this way? Did you check Partial Views?

Comment: Well, I first did it on as separate cshtml files and then I wanted it to be all in one page so just copied the content into one file. However, your suggestion does sound nice so I will implement that just thinking will the issue still be there when I want to return from the controller because at the moment it returns to the top of the page instead of the section of the page that I used to post to the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Redirect to the view like in example;

```
    return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("Index") + "#contactSection");
```

And on the view, right under section tag, place an a tag as below

```
<a id="contactSection"></a>
```

When the action completes, i guess it'll directly focus on contact section.

Hope got your question correctly. Peace out.

Comment: Thank you, you are a legend thanks for answering my first stack overflow question. Hope you have a good day bro.

Comment: I needed to change my ViewBag into a TempData as it did not store my data when using the redirectToAction return so that is the only additional info I will say was needed just for other people who wander onto this answer.

e.g 

 TempData["Message"] = "Your message has been sent";

and in the view had to store it has as a  variable: var message =  TempData["Message"]